# jquery following tag selector

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery problem. The HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a class="pfImg"></a>
    <div><a>Text1</a></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="pfImg"></a>
    <div><a>Text2</a></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In this structure, in every `<li>` there is a picture of a website and when I hover that picture, a div will appear with some text specifically written for that website. The `<li>` has a specified width and the `display: block; overflow: hidden;` set to it. When the `<li>` expands, the div should automatically be shown.
I tried it with jQuery, but didn't find the proper code.

```
var $this = $(this); // EDIT: forgot I had created this variable.
$('.pfImg').hover(
  function() {
    $this.parent().animate({width: '300px'}, 'slow', 'swing');
  },
  function() {
    $this.parent().animate({width: '100px'}, 'slow', 'swing');
}); // end hover
```

Thanks in advance

-- Seht

Comment: You should consider coding in an IDE like IntelliJ that will highlight your errors. In this case, it would tell you that `$this` is undeclared.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(this)` instead of `$this`, You have missed `()` and you need to use `next("div")`

```
$('.pfImg').hover(function () {
    $(this).next("div").animate({
        width: '300px'
    }, 'slow', 'swing');
}, function () {
    $(this).next("div").animate({
        width: '100px'
    }, 'slow', 'swing');
}); // end hover
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you need, you can use `next()` like this:

**FIDDLE** http://jsfiddle.net/5gVRS/

**JQUERY**

```
$('.pfImg').hover(
    function () {
        $(this).next("div").animate({width: '300px'}, 'slow', 'swing');
    },
    function () {
        $(this).next("div").animate({width: '100px'}, 'slow', 'swing');
}); // end hover
```

have a look [here](http://api.jquery.com/next/) to better understand how `next()` works

Answer (score 0):

You need to put "this" in a bracket.

E.g `$(this)`.

Or `$(this).next(div)`

You can give it a try. Not sure which way works best.